# Does anyone know where I might find a file based multi-way B-Tree Class for c#?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, b-tree, multiway-tree

I need to implement a file based multi-way B-Tree Class for c#. There is similar functionality available for C++ and C but I want to use it in C#. It also need to be available as source code as I wish to use with some alternative .NET implementations like MonoTouch.

If anyone knows of a non file based **Multiway b-Tree** then this could adapted faily easily to be file based. You make each Multiway page/array of nodes a record/sector in the file. And save them when they change.

Anyone?

Comment: Without the sorcecode req I would say: Use a (clustered) index in SQL.

Comment: I don't want a full SQL implementation just the raw b-tree index code.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen the B-Tree isn't widely implemented in C#, but I could be wrong.

However a [quick search](http://www.google.com/custom?hl=en&q=B-Tree+c%23&btnG=Search), turned up [this implementation](http://www.valkema.org/?p=5) and the comments look positive.

I scrounged up some stuff of CodePlex:

- [B+ Tree Class](http://kwdata.codeplex.com/)
- [SharpClaw DB Server In C#](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpClaw) <- You may need to hunt for it, but there is one implemented in this project.

Comment: Nice find, but after a quick look I don't think it is File-based.

Comment: Sorry :) I don't think you're gonna find one that meets all your requirements, but something might give you a head start...

Answer (score 0):

Create a [C# wrapper](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=9699) that calls the C/C++ code?

Comment: I could do this if all else failed.... I'd rather port a c/C++ to C# if it came to that.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be what you are looking for: [The WB B-Tree Database for SCM, Java, C#, and C](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/WB)

Comment: NB: The API for this looks very ugly.

Answer (score -1):

C5 - http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

Comment: That contains some binary trees, no (file-based) B-Tree.